# Maven Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory

Tags: maven-2, jakarta-ee, maven-plugin

i am using maven i don't have more knowledge about maven  when i am install my project then it will successfully build but when i am test my project with maven it will give me an error like

```
Unable to copy an artifact to the working directory
```

i gave  all permission to my project directory detail error as below so how can i resolve my 
problem and how to run my project

so please help me

E
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
[INFO] Total time: 1 minute 24 seconds

[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jan 27 17:44:59 IST 2011

[INFO] Final Memory: 35M/84M

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look carefully at the error, you see this line...

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/home/nayan/workspace/ONiT/mediaPlayer/target/classes (Is a directory)
```

While other artifacts are getting copied to the subfolders of `/home/nayan/workspace/ONiT/servlet/`, this one is different.  Most likely `/home/nayan/workspace/ONiT/mediaPlayer/` folder does not exist or does not have `write` permission.